# Firewire 800 Card

Tags: firewire

Can anyone recommend a Firewire 800 card compatible with the usual 32-bit PCI, or PCI Express slots found in most machines? I have only found a card compatible with PCI-64.

I also found a [Belkin PCI-Express card](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-Express-Firewire-Card-Ports/dp/B000HOJT4M/ref=sr_1_38?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1255381044&sr=8-38) with horrible reviews, which I am hence looking to avoid.

Must be compatible with Windows Server 2k3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16800998060 - PCI
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815150151 - PCIe

Get the PCIe card if you can.  Much faster.

For servers, I generally wouldn't go with SIIG right off the bat because it's more of a consumer level device.  I'd look to Adaptec, LSI, or ATTO for server class expansion cards, however I wasn't able to find anything from them but didn't search extensively.  Google is your friend :).  The problem is, FireWire is also targeted towards consumer level, so finding a "server class" card could be difficult.